# iOS Push and Pop view controller at the same time

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewcontroller, navigation

I am currently working on an Xamarin iOS application that has some navigation issues.

What i am currently trying to achieve is to push a ViewController while at the same time popping the previous one off.  The reason for this is that I have one ViewController that shows some specific questions from this view controller i can spin up another ViewController of the same type and the user can fill in some more questions.  What i want to be able to do is pop the previous filled in view controller so when the user hits the back navigation it takes me back to my home view controller (and not through all the previous instances of the question controller).

I also can't use the PopToRoot or PopToViewController.

I have tried doing a pop without animation and a push with animation and results in a quick flicker of the underneath viewController which is colourful so its a bit of a shock to the eyes.

The other thing I have tried is to manipulate the navigation stack underneath by pushing on the questionController and then removing from the stack the old viewController the problem with that is i have some tear down on the ViewDidDisappear (i work out if its a pop disappear rather than just a cover up) which doesnt seem to be called because of the manual removal.  So along this method is it ok to call the ViewDidDisappear to carry out my unwiring so there is no leaks?

Many Thanks for your time reading.

Comment: Please, share us some code you've tryes

Comment: unfortunately i don't have any as I'm just working on stuff if it doesnt work i just modify it.  Sorry.

Comment: Not sure about the Xamarin but native navigation controller has a method setViewController into which you can inject an array of controllers to show. This means you need to grab the current array of controllers, remove the last controller from the array and append the new controller on it. Then set this array as the view controllers to the navigation controller.

Comment: Hi Matic thank you for your reply - that was the manipulated navigation stack that i was referring to but with that approach I'm just worried about leaking because the lifecycle isn't really being honoured or am i missing something?

Comment: *"I also can't use the PopToRoot or PopToViewController."* Why not? That would be the proper way to do what you want.

Comment: The reason is the PopToRoot would take me back to far up the navigation stack.

The PopToViewController would still cause the blink that i am trying to avoid.  Ideally what i would like to happen is the push animation to occur and then (unknown to the user) the underneath controller is popped.  Maybe the manipulation of the navigation stack like Matic says is the only way.

Comment: "The PopToViewController would still cause the blink that i am trying to avoid." What blink? That should simply pop the current view controller and all others on the stack to expose the view controller you're popping "too". It will animate that transition using the standard pop animation, which should be correct.

Comment: Sorry, I must not have explained it correctly.  So say I have this navigation:

ViewController1
ViewController2
ViewController3 (say this is the questionController)

So what i want to do is to push on another ViewController3 and remove the alreadyExisting ViewController3.  

Using the PopToView would take me back to ViewController2 then push on the new ViewController3, so u would see part of ViewController2 as ViewController3 animates in.  Thats what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Using `setViewControllers` is the correct way to do that.

Comment: ok cool thanks dan - guess i will remove the tear down into a new method and call it on the viewDidDisappear as well as this new way too.  Thanks for the input